# How to populate a textbox based on the selected value of a dropdown list in an asp.net c# web forms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list (doc_rvw_sub_recip_list) that is populated with names from tbl_ad_users.  tbl_ad_users contains a field titled "domain_user".  I would like to populate an asp:hiddenfield (hdn_domain_user) with the "domain_user" based on the selected value in the doc_rvw_sub_recip_list dropdown list.  For testing I used a dropdown list (domain_user_ddl) instead of a hidden field, and it works as needed.  But I don't know how to get the value into a hidden field as opposed to using a dropdown list.

The following is doc_rvw_sub_recip_list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="doc_rvw_sub_recip_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdc_ad_user_list" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="email_address" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true"><asp:ListItem Value="">Please Select</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
```

The following is the sql data source for domain_user_ddl:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdc_domain_user_ddl" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:idrfConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [domain_user] FROM [tbl_ad_users] WHERE ([email_address] = @email_address)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="doc_rvw_sub_recip_list" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="email_address" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The following is domain_user_ddl:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="domain_user_ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdc_domain_user_ddl" DataTextField="domain_user" DataValueField="domain_user" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

How do I get this to work for hdn_domain_user just as it works for domain_user_ddl?

Comment: In order to populate page data based on user input (in a very generic sense), you're either going to have to use AJAX after the input has been provided in order to dynamically fetch the results for the page data or you're going to have to post the form and re-load the page to include the input results.

Comment: Why dont you do it using back end code?

Comment: @TheUnknown I would like to do this using back end code, but I don't know how to do this yet.  I found [link]http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/762475/How-to-Auto-populate-text-boxes-when-selecting-val.  I'm attempting to get it working, but I'm not having much success.  I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ASPX**

Add a OnSelectedIndexChanged event to your dropdown...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="doc_rvw_sub_recip_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdc_ad_user_list" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="email_address" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="doc_rvw_sub_recip_list_SelectedIndexChanged"><asp:ListItem Value="">Please Select</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
```

Add your hidden field...

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn_domain_user" />
```

**Code Behind**

Handle the SelectedIndexChanged event...

```
protected void doc_rvw_sub_recip_list_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Populate the hidden field if the dropdown has a selected value
    if (doc_rvw_sub_recip_list.SelectedValue != null)
        hdn_domain_user.Value = doc_rvw_sub_recip_list.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed!